# javascript: calculate x% of a number

Tags: javascript, math

I am wondering how in javascript if i was given a number (say 10000) and then was given a percentage (say 35.8%)

how would I work out how much that is (eg 3580)

Comment: You would multiply the number by 35.8%, which is `var number=10000; alert(number*0.358);`

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```
var result = (35.8 / 100) * 10000;
```

(Thank you [jball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223391/jball) for this change of order of operations. I didn't consider it).

Comment: You don't need brackets there.

Comment: @Klaster_1 Yeah, just trying to show the relationship more clearer. You could say I don't need semicolons either, or `var`, or whitspace, but it wouldn't be very readable or good code would it? :P

Comment: Switching the order of operations avoids the floating point problem, e.g., `var result = pct / 100 * number;`

Comment: Why are dividing the 10000? Sure, it gives the correct answer, but it's semantically meaningless.

Comment: @Ryan Fox Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Ryan Fox The 10000 here is the TOTAL amount you want to calculate the percentage (35.8) for.

Comment: @jball this can still lead to floating point problems.  For instance, calculating 10% of 20.05 gives 2.0050000000000003.  In order to fix floating point issues, I believe you have to normalize both the original amount and the percent to integers before doing any calculations.  I'll post my own answer with how I resolved this.

Answer (score 17):

This is what I would do:

```
// num is your number
// amount is your percentage
function per(num, amount){
  return num*amount/100;
}

...
<html goes here>
...

alert(per(10000, 35.8));
```

Answer (score 10):

Your percentage divided by 100 (to get the percentage between 0 and 1) times by the number

```
35.8/100*10000
```

Answer (score 8):

Best thing is to memorize balance equation in natural way.

```
Amount / Whole = Percentage / 100
```

---

usually You have one variable missing, in this case it is Amount

```
Amount / 10000 = 35.8 / 100
```

then you have high school math (proportion) to multiple outer from both sides and inner from both sides.

```
Amount * 100 = 358 000

Amount = 3580
```

It works the same in all languages and on paper. JavaScript is no exception.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass the % as part of your function you should use the following alternative:

```
<script>
function fpercentStr(quantity, percentString)
{
    var percent = new Number(percentString.replace("%", ""));
    return fpercent(quantity, percent);
}

function fpercent(quantity, percent)
{
    return quantity * percent / 100;
}
document.write("test 1:  " + fpercent(10000, 35.873))
document.write("test 2:  " + fpercentStr(10000, "35.873%"))
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I use two very useful JS functions:
http://blog.bassta.bg/2013/05/rangetopercent-and-percenttorange/

```
function rangeToPercent(number, min, max){
   return ((number - min) / (max - min));
}
```

and

```
function percentToRange(percent, min, max) {
   return((max - min) * percent + min);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to fully avoid floating point issues, the amount whose percent is being calculated and the percent itself need to be converted to integers.  Here's how I resolved this:

```
function calculatePercent(amount, percent) {
    const amountDecimals = getNumberOfDecimals(amount);
    const percentDecimals = getNumberOfDecimals(percent);
    const amountAsInteger = Math.round(amount + `e${amountDecimals}`);
    const percentAsInteger = Math.round(percent + `e${percentDecimals}`);
    const precisionCorrection = `e-${amountDecimals + percentDecimals + 2}`;    // add 2 to scale by an additional 100 since the percentage supplied is 100x the actual multiple (e.g. 35.8% is passed as 35.8, but as a proper multiple is 0.358)

    return Number((amountAsInteger * percentAsInteger) + precisionCorrection);
}

function getNumberOfDecimals(number) {
    const decimals = parseFloat(number).toString().split('.')[1];

    if (decimals) {
        return decimals.length;
    }

    return 0;
}

calculatePercent(20.05, 10); // 2.005
```

As you can see, I:

1. Count the number of decimals in both the `amount` and the `percent`
2. Convert both `amount` and `percent` to integers using exponential notation
3. Calculate the exponential notation needed to determine the proper end value
4. Calculate the end value

The usage of exponential notation was inspired by [Jack Moore's blog post](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/).  I'm sure my syntax could be shorter, but I wanted to be as explicit as possible in my usage of variable names and explaining each step.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a bit pedantic / redundant with its numeric casting, but here's a safe function to calculate percentage of a given number:

```
function getPerc(num, percent) {
    return Number(num) - ((Number(percent) / 100) * Number(num));
}

// Usage: getPerc(10000, 25);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var number = 10000;
var result = .358 * number;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Harder Way (learning purpose) :**

```
var number = 150
var percent= 10
var result = 0
for (var index = 0; index < number; index++) {
   const calculate = index / number * 100
   if (calculate == percent) result += index
}
return result
```