# Why doesn't my function calculate percentages as expected?

Tags: javascript

```
var allBills = [124,48,268,180];
var tips =[];
//var total = [];
document.write(allBills);

function calcIt(bill){
  for (i=0; i < bill.length; i++){
    if(bill[i] < 50){
      tips[i] = bill[i] * 20% + " ";
    }else if(bill > 50 && bill <200){
      tips[i] = bill[i] * 15% + " ";
    }else {
      tips[i] = bill[i] * 10% + " ";
    }
    return tips += tips[i];

  };

document.write(calcIt(allBills));
```

I am trying to multiply for each restaurant bill **var allBills = [124,48,268,180]**; , Why is this not working?

Comment: `10%` is not how you do percentages

Comment: `bill[i] * 0.2` for `20%`

Comment: ^^ In other words -- what's the **mathematical** representation of `10%`?  How would you use a calculator to figure it?

Comment: Dupe: [javascript: calculate x% of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4372902/2415822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For percentages, you can either divide by `100` or simply use percentage as follow: `100 = 1, 90 = .9, 50 = .5, 15 = .15, 5 = .05`, and so on.
2. Wrap the calculation with parentheses to avoid any clash with the strings.

*I used `toFixed(2)` just for readability*

```js
var allBills = [124, 48, 268, 180];

function calcIt(bill) {
  var tips = [];
  for (i = 0; i < bill.length; i++) {
    if (bill[i] < 50) tips[i] = (bill[i] * .2).toFixed(2) + " ";
    else if (bill > 50 && bill < 200) tips[i] = (bill[i] * .15).toFixed(2) + " ";
    else tips[i] = (bill[i] * .1).toFixed(2) + " ";
  }
  
  return tips;
}

document.write(calcIt(allBills).join(" | "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using reminder operator (%) , which provides the reminder. Your logic does not fit with what you are expecting. If you want to add the % symbol to your out put then use it as a string